# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RVAideMemoire’

Tags: r

I tried a simple

```
install.packages('RVAideMemoire')
```

And it just kept running numbers but not downloading, so I went to the website and downloaded it manually.

```
install.packages('RVAideMemoire.tgz', lib='destination_directory',repos = NULL)
```

Now I have RVAideMemoire in RStudio. It says it's installed in the User Library instead of the system library. But when I run the following I get an error

```
> library(RVAideMemoire)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘ade4’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘RVAideMemoire’ was built under R version 3.3.0 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RVAideMemoire’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install manually, you don't automatically get dependencies installed.

Looking at the [package's page on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RVAideMemoire/index.html), the following the following non-recommended (i.e. not installed by default) packages are imported (and hence required):

```
deps <- c("ade4", "car", "cramer", "dunn.test", "FactoMineR", 
       "lme4", "mixOmics", "multcompView", "pls", "pspearman",
       "statmod", "vegan")
install.packages(deps)
```

If your package installation machinery is messed up for some reason, you'll have to install all of these packages (and *their* dependencies) manually ...

```
devtools::package_deps("RVAideMemoire")
```

could be useful too.

Comment: Do you have any idea why install.packages('RVAideMemoire') isn't working? Should it take more than a few minutes to install?

Comment: Nope. I'm using repository https://cran.rstudio.com , takes a minute or less to install (Linux, R-devel).