# trouble with "DataCombine" and "dplyr"

Tags: r, dplyr, slide

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the "dplyr" package I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I've installed both the package "DataCombine" and "dplyr" to enable me to lag some variables in a regression using the slide() function. I have run it successfully in the past on my console. However, for some reason, R has stopped letting me use this function, and it keeps displaying the following error messages:

When I try doing library(DataCombine), this is what displays:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DataCombine’ in loadNamespace(j 
 <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘dplyr’
In addition: Warning message:
 package ‘DataCombine’ was built under R version 3.4.1
```

Though instead, sometimes it displays this:

```
> library(DataCombine)
Warning messages:
1: package ‘DataCombine’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
2: Installed Rcpp (0.12.11) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr 
(0.12.12).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.
```

And when I try doing slide() with some data inside, this is what displays:

```
Error in slide(mydata2, Var = "AdjPP", slideBy = -4) : 
 could not find function "slide"
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you do `library(dplyr)`? Have you tried reinstalling both packages?

Comment: @Gregor 21 I had tried reinstalling, but to no avail. However, when I did the following, instead of just normal install.packages(DataCombine), it worked again: 'install.packages("DataCombine", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")' 
'library(DataCombine)'. Still know luck with "dplyr" though, unfortunately, and no understanding as to why what I did worked for "DatCombine"...

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your previous commands, especially the loading of your libraries, to make your error reproducable. 
Skimming around stackoverflow [Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RVAideMemoire’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149457/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-rvaidememoire) I think you have maybe manually installed your packages. Thereby some dependencies between the packages might not be set up properly.

If you just use:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("DataCombine")
library(dplyr)
library(DataCombine)
```

The error should not occour.

Comment: I had used those to install the packages, but still got the error message. 
        install.packages("DataCombine", repos = "cloud.r-project.org/")' 
        'library(DataCombine) worked for some reason though, which I don't understand

Comment: what OS do you have? This can also be a potential source

Comment: I have Windows 10